# Boxes floated to the left get pushed over to the right when expanded with jQuery

Tags: html, css

The best way I can explain this is with a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/8tXku/

I'm floating each `.project` div to the left and using some simple jQuery to make them expand to show a description when clicked, however if you click the first project it will push the third project to the right, because it's taking up too much space when expanded.

Is there a way to get the third project div to just gracefully move down the page with the expanded content rather than move over to the right?

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior that you describe in Chrome. It seems to work just as you desire.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome as well, if you arrange the preview so that there are two boxes per row, and then click on project #1, project #3 will jump to the right. I want to make it move down instead of jumping to the right.

Comment: If a height is defined on `.project`, the problem disappears.

Comment: I don't think I can define height though, as the project description can vary so setting a fixed height may break it?

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/8tXku/1/, now the project description hides behind the third project div.

Comment: Add some margin-top to each .project, and set the description to position:absolute; the description will slide down without affecting the layout. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/yJMtT/ I had to make .project's width a little bit smaller because of my screen.

Comment: This would work, however the project description can be of variable length, meaning I don't know the exact height for each project. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/yJMtT/1/ you can see that the project description hides behind another project.

Comment: @JamesDawson Check my Answer, I fixed it the best way I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a dirty solution but its works perfectly.

Giving the `.project-description` a `position:absolute;` will allow it to `.slideDown()` without affecting the surrounding `divs`, yet some other tweaks had to be made.

I added `position:relative;` to `.project` so that each `.project-description` is contained within it.

**Final CSS**

```
.project {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
position:relative;
}

.project-description {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/N4U3R/

**UPDATE**

When `.project-description` contains a big text (obviously) it will be hidden under the bottom div, just add `z-index:99;` to `.project-description`

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/pMGDZ/

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.project-description` current style with this

```
.project-description {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    width:325px;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1;    
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/8tXku/4/